# Evidences regarding Lord Shiva eating meat

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, non-vegetarian

[Lord Shiva](https://www.google.com/search?q=lord%20shiva&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&prmd=ibnv&sxsrf=ALiCzsalCAcQ-yKCq4S7OMhL_MhJOdy5dg:1657438531478&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY657X5-34AhX61zgGHVD3AyoQ_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=360&bih=674&dpr=2#imgrc=-MVRNrUsR85aEM)

Does the scriptures describe whether Lord Shiva consumes meat?

Does the ShivPuran describe whether Lord Shiva consumes meat?

Comment: There are no mythologies in Hinduism. There are ithihasas puranas which talks of history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And since he burns and oppresses, is keen and fierce, and endued with great energy, and **is engaged in eating flesh and blood and marrow, he is said to be Rudra.**

> [Source](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b126.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The God doesn't (need) consume any meat or food, in general, for he's not a normal human with hunger and thirst like desires.

However, He's offered meat in his certain aspects like Bhairava and other forms and god Shiva being bounteous, accepts all offerings of a devotee, provided the devotee does it with deep love and devotion.

Such an example is narrated in the Gautami Mahatmya of the Brahma Purāṇa. **God Brahmā narrates the famous story of Bhilla-tirtha, where Shiva accepted the killed animal's meat offerings by a low caste hunter as his *Naivedya*.**

> #### [Chapter 99](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/gautami-mahatmya/d/doc216830.html) - The Holy Centre Bhilla (Gautami Mahatmya), Brahma Purāṇa
>
> > - 7-13. After wandering in various places and killing animals as he
> >   pleased he used to place the meat at the tip of the bow. The tired
> >   hunter then came to the place where Lord Śiva, Ādikeśa had his Liṅga.
> >   He used to keep the meat outside. Then he went to Gaṅgā and taking
> >   water in his mouth and some leaves in his hand, he returned to the
> >   lord with great devotion. **He took the meat in the other hand for
> >   offering Naivedya with great devotion**. He then came to Lord Ādikeśa
> >   who had already been worshipped elaborately by Veda (the sage of that
> >   name). He then removed flowers left by Veda after his worship by means
> >   of his foot. After bathing lord Śiva with the water brought by him in
> >   his mouth and after offering those leaves by way of worship **he used to
> >   place the meat there as Naivedya saying “May lord Śiva be pleased with
> >   me.”**
>
> > - Excepting devotion of a splendid nature unto Śiva he did not know
> >   anything else. Thereafter he used to go back to his own abode in the
> >   manner he had come, taking the rest of the meat with him.
>
> > 14. **Everyday he used to come there and do this by himself. However, Īśa was pleased with him. Indeed, wonderful are the ways of the lord.**
>
> > 15. As long as the Bhilla did not come to Him, Lord Śiva was not happy. Who knows the (magnitude of) Śiva’s compassion towards his
> >     devotees? It is beyond all measure.

- Also, as per [this forum](https://such.forumotion.com/t42727-according-to-skanda-upapurana-lord-shiva-enjoyed-eating-meat), Shiva also accepted meat offering from his another devotee (named Dhira), as narrated by Rishi Agastya, in the Chapter 29 of the [*Shiva-Bhakta-vilasam*](https://bookstore.sriramanamaharshi.org/product/siva-bhakta-vilasamtelugu/) as narrated by Sage Upanmayu in Skanda puranam 
   (*Pages 102-121; translated by Lineshwara Rao;
  published by Shri Ramanashram*)

However, note that **the Shiva Purāṇa Verse [1.25.43](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225964.html) forbids meat for the devotees of Shiva.**